# R - Target a different columns based on earlier input

Tags: r, variables, eval

I want to allow an part earlier in the script to select which of two columns is referenced by later parts of the script. I have tried a few functions like `get()`, `parse()`, and `eval()`, but none have achieve the desired effect.

Attempt:

```
df = data.frame(column1 = c(1,2,3,4,5), column2 = c('a','b','c','d','e'))

targetcolumn = "column1"

df$eval(targetcolumn)
```

expected:
contents of `df$column1`; aka `1,2,3,4,5`

actual result:
`Error: attempt to apply non-function`

Comment: Use `[[` instead of `$` i.e. `df[[targetcolumn]]`.  If you want eval/parse, you may have to do this on the whole expression `eval(parse(text = sprintf("df$%s", targetcolumn)))#[1] 1 2 3 4 5`